# How to get last tuesday of particular month

Tags: apex, date

I am having issue in finding the last Tuesday of particular month. 
i just have a date being passed to the method i want to get last Tuesday of month of that date.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the apex code you reference in your post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
public static Date lastTuesdayOfMonth(Date d) {

    // Last day of month
    Date last = Date.newInstance(
            d.year(),
            d.month(),
            Date.daysInMonth(d.year(), d.month())
            );

    // A Tuesday (but depends on locale setting for start of week)
    Date tuesday = last.toStartOfWeek().addDays(2);

    // Make sure it is a Tuesday within the month
    if (tuesday > last) tuesday = tuesday.addDays(-7);

    return tuesday;
}
```

Refer to the various [Date class methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm) for more detail.